# Optimization for tweets request in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I would like to list all tweets posted by users followed by the current user (the same as you see when you login to twitter).

Currently I have the following statement:

```
@tweets = Tweet.includes(:user).where(user_id: current_user.followed.pluck(:id))
```

It works well, but I suppose it is awful from performance standpoint.

Could you please tell, what is the most efficient query in my case?

UPDATE: I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tweets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :followerships, class_name: 'Followership', foreign_key: 'followed_id'
    has_many :followedships, class_name: 'Followership', foreign_key: 'follower_id'
    has_many :followers, through: :followerships, source: :follower
    has_many :followed, through: :followedships, source: :followed
end

class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end

class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is output for `[my_query].explain`

```
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "followerships" ON "users"."id" = "followerships".    "followed_id" WHERE "followerships"."follower_id" = ?  [["follower_id", 4]]
  Tweet Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tweets".* FROM "tweets" WHERE "tweets"."user_id" IN (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13,     14, 15)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15)
 => EXPLAIN for: SELECT "tweets".* FROM "tweets"  WHERE "tweets"."user_id" IN (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE tweets USING INDEX index_tweets_on_user_id (user_id=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1

EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IN (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE users USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
```

Comment: Have you identified this as a performance issue? On the surface, this looks like a micro-optimization.

Comment: I think this code will be generated one (Rails are clever enough to build subquery) or two queries. And it should work rather fast. You can try `EXPLAIN` the query to see if it can be accelerated (maybe add some index).

Comment: It would be useful to see the models and associations. This ought to be a single query, as long as the models are associated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I run `explain`, and it turns out that I have 3 queries. Is there something wrong with the model?